# Does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(t) \,dt $ converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

Does  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(t) \,dt $ converge or diverge? How would I prove it?

Should I use 'principle value' to do:
$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a \sin(t)\,dt$$

Comment: What you propose would be called a "principal value" of the integral.  But in fact the integral does not converge in the more stringent sense that mathematicians normally use.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin (t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ converge?

No, for the limit to exist with limit $L$, then for every pair of sequences $a_n\to-\infty$ and $b_n\to\infty$, we would have that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{a_n}^{b_n} \sin (t)\,\mathrm{d}t = L$$
which is obviously not the case.

The [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is different to usual convergence and this value *does* exist, it is
$$\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a\sin (t) \,\mathrm{d} t = 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{-a}^a \sin(t)\,dt=0$$
for $a>0$ since sine is an odd function. Hence

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a \sin(t)\,dt=0.$$

Comment: $a>0$ is not required.  e.g., $\int_\pi^{-\pi} \sin t \, dt = 0$, etc.