# How to prove $\int^\infty_{-\infty}x dx$ is divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Well, intuitively, I thought $\int^\infty_{-\infty}x dx$ is $0$
 ,but the answer is divergent.

How to prove $\int^\infty_{-\infty}x dx$ is divergent?

Comment: What's the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ that you are working with?

Comment: It is true that $\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_{-a}^a x\,dx = 0$. However, that's not the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$ that I use, and my guess is that it's not the definition you use either, if you read up on what your book says about improper integrals. How to prove it's divergent depends on exactly what definition you have, though.

Comment: Yes, the integral is divergent because the limits $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b x dx$ and $\lim_{a\to -\infty}\int_a^0 x dx$ do not exist.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I'm using the Riemann Integral. The answer depends on the definition?? Sorry I'm not familiar the calculus well

Comment: Evaluating it you would get $\frac {x^2}2$ and if you plug in values you get $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\,\mathrm dx = \frac {\infty^2}2 - \frac {\infty^2}2=\infty -\infty=$Undefined. Not a real answer but then, there is no real answer to $\infty - \infty$ because $\infty$ is a concept. not a number, as I have learnt so far.

Comment: @shashack The Riemann integral is for functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$. How do you define an integral of the type $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$? In this case, the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$, not an interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Oh, I checked again the improper integral's definition.
For all $t >= a$,  $\int^{t}_{a} f(x) dx$ exists and the follow limit value also exists then, $\int^{\infty}_{a} f(x) dx = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \int^{t}_{a} f(x) dx$

Comment: @shashack That defines $\int_a^{+\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ for a fixed $a$. But my question was: how do you define $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x) dx = \int^{a}_{-\infty} f(x) dx + \int^{\infty}_{a} f(x) dx $ when the right hand side's integrals exists. So, yes. since the right side's integrals are divergent. My question's answer is also divergent.

Answer (score 4):

This is very closely related to the question on whether $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin x\,\mathrm d x$ converges, where I [responded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285752/does-int-infty-infty-sint-dt-converge/2285760#2285760).

The answer is the following:

No, the integral does not converge (It is divergent). If it did converge to some limit $L$, then for every pair of sequences $a_n\to-\infty$ and $b_n\to\infty$, we would have that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{a_n}^{b_n}x \,\mathrm{d} x = L$$
But this is not the case. This is easily proven, try for example the case with $a_n = -n$ and $b_n = 2n$. In this case $a_n\to -\infty$ and $b_n\to+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$ but the value of the integral does not go to zero.

The important take-home message is that when we consider limits, they must converge to the same limit no matter the path. No matter how we approach the limit. Otherwise it is not considered convergent. In this instance it should not matter how the lower bound goes to minus infinity and how the upper limit goes to plus infinity, but it does matter. **We conclude that the integral is divergent.**

The [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is different to usual convergence (And is therefore *not* what is being asked in the problem) and this value *does* exist, it is
$$\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a x \,\mathrm{d} x = 0.$$

Comment: Could you please explain what is different from my deleted answer, Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi I think your answer was not that clear (I didn't downvote, though). Were you saying that the integral converged or not? Does my answer any of your questions?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The improper integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f$ exists, if both $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}f$ and $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f$ exists and finite. And then $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} \int\limits_{-a}^{a}f$.
In the case of $f(x)=x$, the improper integrals are not finite. And in the case of $f(x)=\sin(x)$, they don't exists, because the $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \cos(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: You right. Thank you guys!!

Comment: @shashack I've added some additional information.

Answer (score 2):

The integral $\int^\infty_{-\infty}x dx$ does not converge .

We can get two different answers by taking two different limits $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^{n}x \,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{(-n)^2}{2}\right]=0$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^{2n}x \,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{(2n)^2}{2}-\frac{(-n)^2}{2}\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n^2}{2}=\infty$$

Two different answers are not possible so the integral does not exist.

The correct way to evaluate $\int^\infty_{-\infty}x dx$ is: $$ \lim_{a \rightarrow - \infty , b \rightarrow \infty} \int_a ^ b f(x) \, dx $$ the integral exists if and only if the limit exists.

However, note that the Cauchy principal value exists, $$PV\int^\infty_{-\infty}x dx=0$$

Comment: This is the best answer. :)