# Why does the expected value of given PDF not exist?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, density-function

For exam preparation I try to solve the following question:

Does the expected value exist for the density function $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \; \mathrm{d}x$

As I understand it I need to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\;dx$ converges

$$
\text{finding antiderivative}\\
\\
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+1} \; \mathrm{d}x\\
\\
\text{substitute}\;u = x^2+1, du = 2x\\
\\
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u} \; \mathrm{d}u = \frac{ln(\lvert u \rvert)}{2\pi} \Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty}\\
\\
\text{back substitution I get}\\
\\
\frac{ln(x^2+1)}{2\pi} \Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 0
$$

So the integral exist and converges. What I am doing wrong here?

Any comment is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The integral for the expected value exists as a Cauchy principal value. The integrand being an odd function about $x=0$ gives you the zero you're getting.

Comment: For more detail, you can also check out [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610315/how-to-prove-int-infty-inftyx-dx-is-divergent]

Comment: Regarding the first comment. Though, it's correct that one can give meaning to the integral by means of P.V., I don't think that it's too helpful here, or instructive. If you want to see, why this integral is not converging, read the wiki article on 'improper integrals'.

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u} \; \mathrm{d}u = \frac{ln(\lvert u \rvert)}{2\pi} \Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty}\\
$$
is not correct.  In fact, these four integrals all diverge:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{u}\;du = +\infty
\\
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{u}\;du = +\infty
\\
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{u}\;du = -\infty
\\
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{u}\;du = -\infty
$$
When we say
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u} \; \mathrm{d}u
$$
converges, we mean those four integrals all converge.